# Images with size more than 1 mb are not able to be uploaded to my django website hosted on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, file-upload, web-hosting

My Django website is hosted on AWS, and I am using PostgreSQL database from AWS RDS. For media files I am using local directory of application.

```
mywebsite--
        |--home--
        |--mywebsite--
           |--media--
              |<location for media files>
```

and I have my website asking for uploading an image

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="imagesubmit"></input>
```

I have tried a model with defining ImageField as well as FileField. But still, the images which are less than 1 MB can be uploaded to the server, but images with size more than 1 MB could not be. Although when I tried FileField in a model with uploading the pdf file instead of the image, it is working fine for pdf files with size more than 1 MB. 
I check my uploaded image or file by this.

```
<a href="{{user.userprofile.file.url}}" target="_blank">click here to see uploaded file</a>
```

here user.userprofile (one to one relationship) and file is model field (test1 with ImageField and test2 with FileField) defined inside the userprofile model.
I have searched many places, but I could not get the answer to why this problem is happening to me. I want to make the user able to upload any size of the image file.

Comment: Is it possible to upload on localhost? Did you get any error?

Comment: Yes, it is. moreover for large files I had to change the mode of media folder in hosted instance from 755 to 777(chmod 777 /opt/python/bundle/version/app/project/media) to read them by clicking the test link (the "a" tag as mentioned in question)

Comment: If it's possible to upload in localhost, the problem might be due to the ***timeout***. Try to increase the default timeout settings of aws/nginix server if you have